# Java while loop repeats and doesn’t exit when code reaches the end

Tags: java

I'm very inexperienced with coding, and am trying to make a very basic text based rpg combat system using my limited knowledge and the internet. Ideally the program should allow you to choose a type of attack, take the stamina cost away from your max stamina, then tell you how much damage you've done. As of now I am just trying to get the "normal attack" to work, but whenever you run the code and choose an attack it continuously just repeats the instructions on how to attack. I have included both the code and a screenshot of what displays when running. I assume the problem lies with me misusing the while loop, as I don't know much about it.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RPGv1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nWelcome to RPGv1 " + name + "!");

        // Max Stats
        int MaxHP = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
        int MaxMP = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
        int MaxStam = 15;

        // Enemy 1 Stats
        int En1HP = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int En1Stam = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

        // Combat
        System.out.println("You are being approached by the evil Enemy 1!");


        while (En1HP > 0) {
                System.out.println("Type \"n\" to use your Normal Attack, \"h\" for your Heavy Attack, and \"f\" for your fireball.");
                String combat = scan.nextLine();
            if (combat == "n")
                if (MaxStam >= 2) { //required stamina
                    int nDam = rand.nextInt(3) + 1; //damage
                    int nStam = rand.nextInt(5) + 1; //stamina use
                    MaxStam = MaxStam - nStam; //stamina being taken
                    System.out.println("You have dealt " + nDam + " damage, and have " + MaxStam + " Stamina remaining.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You do not have enough stamina.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUwvz.png)

Comment: Your loop condition depends on `En1HP`, a variable which is never assigned to inside of the loop.

Comment: `En1HP` never updated inside the loop.

Comment: You need to substract the nDam from En1HP to make it zero.

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Your code is also suffering from comparison of `String`s with `==` instead of `equals`. The snippet `combat == "n"` is almost guaranteed to be false. Use `combat.equals("n")` or `Objects.equals(combat, "n")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are never updating the value of `En1HP` variable, so it always remaings greater than 0, and thus loops goes for infinite.

To break the loop, you must need to update `En1HP` variable and set its value to less than zero on some condition.

Also as a code conventions, you should use camel-case naming convention for naming variable names.

Comment: I changed if (combat == "n") to if (combat.equals("n")) and it fixed the loop restarting every new line.